# this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Is it safe to call it more than a few times in my Windows Phone Application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dispatcher, begininvoke

I was wondering if it was safe to call the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` in my Windows Phone Application more than a few times. I'm using it call my Methods that populate LongListSelectors and Begin a StoryBoard animation simultaneously.

**Code:**

```
            stbInit.Begin();

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                GetAlbums();
            });

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                GetArtists();
            });

              this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                GetSongs();

            });
```

^ Is this a good way of doing it or should I be calling them all in a single Dispatcher thread? What are the drawbacks / benefits of the above approach? Many thanks.

Comment: Ideally you'd do whatever you need to do that *doesn't* interact with the UI on a separate thread *then* use something like `BeginInvoke` to interact with the UI.  It's much easier if you can use `async/await` and a create an `Async` method to do the non-UI work...

Comment: You're right! Why didn't I think about that in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still calling them all in a single dispatcher thread, a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) represents a queue of calls for a single thread. Your code queues up 3 calls to that single thread. **You are not performing the three actions in parallel in your posted code, they each get processed one after another** (you mention "simultaneously" in your question so I just wanted to make that fact clear).

To answer "Is it better", I ask you a counter question: Is it better to do 3 calls each doing one operation or 1 call doing 3 operations in normal programming without threads involved?

It is really up to the programmer to decide which is "better" in this case. At 3 calls it does not really matter which you do, both will work equally well, just choose whichever one you feel keeps your code most maintainable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understand what a Dispatcher is and does. It does take a bit of a time as my Methods get a List of Albums, Artists and Songs. What would be thes best approach according to you to have them called progressively without affecting the UI to a great extent?

Comment: @NavikGoswami basicly do what Peter Ritchie said in the comments, do the slow work on a background thread (or multiple threads) and update the UI when done. If possible modify your three Get functions to use async I/O calls to whatever they are talking to and you can then just start all 3 of them up then do `await Task.WhenAll(...)` to wait for the 3 to finish and then you won't need threads at all.

Answer (score 0):

All Dispatcher does is that it "forwards" method calls to the primary (UI) thread. It is necessary when performing some kind of UI work (or even creating Bitmap image).

It is fine as long as this code does not take too much time because it then can block your UI and render application unresponsive.